# Distribute a Flink operator evenly across taskmanagers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm prototyping a Flink streaming application on a bare-metal cluster of 15 machines. I'm using yarn-mode with 90 task slots (15x6).

The app reads data from a single Kafka topic. The Kafka topic has 15 partitions, so I set the parallelism of the source operator to 15 as well. However, I found that Flink in some cases assigns 2-4 instances of the consumer task to the same taskmanager. This causes certain nodes to become network-bound (the Kafka topic is serving high volume of data and the machines only have 1G NICs) and bottlenecks in the entire data flow.

Is there a way to "force" or otherwise instruct Flink to distribute a task evenly across all taskmanagers, perhaps round robin? And if not, is there a way to manually assign tasks to specific taskmanager slots?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible. The job manager, which schedules tasks into task slots, is only aware of task slots. It isn't aware that some task slots belong to one task manager, and others to another task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Flink does not allow manually assign task slots as in case of failure handling, it can distribute the task to remaining task managers.

However, you can distribute the workload evenly by setting `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true` in `flink-conf.yaml`.
This works for Flink >= 1.9.2.

To make it work, you may also have to set:
`taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` equal to the number of available CPUs per machine, and
`parallelism.default` equal to the the total number of CPUs in the cluster.

Comment: Do 'cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots' this works on yarn?