# How to increase number of taskmanagers in flink 1.9.0 or latest versions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 1452 independent tasks in a flink job. It reads from kafka. Then do some transformation using flatmap and then sinks in hdfs files. Kafka and and flatmap has parallelism of 20 each and i have 1450 independent sink each having parallelism of 1. As maximum parallelism is 20 here. Flink creates only 5 taskmanagers when i use 4 slots per taskmanagers. As number of total tasks in job is very high i need more taskmanagers to be created.

As of now i am giving more parallelism(100) to one of the sink task so that i get desired number of taskmanagers(which is not a proper way) but it  leads to all sink tasks(except the one with 100 task slots) to be created on only one taskmanager and remaning taskmanager is used by other tasks.

So i need some way to instantiate desired number of taskmanagers in fink and some way to distribute sink tasks into all taskmanagers.

Comment: Could you please clarify a couple of points ? 1) what is your deployment mode - standalone or containerized ? 2) what is your `flink-conf.yaml` current settings for taskmanager ? 3) Am I understand correctly you need to get more slots ? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @MikalaiLushchytski i am using per job (i.e containerized) mode on yarn cluster. There is no setting for taskmanagers in config file. We provide required details from cli arguments(like required memeory, slots etc). Yes I need more slots(it should not depend on task parallelism).

Comment: Can you share what the job graph looks like? It's not clear to me what's going on. It would also be interesting to know why you have so many distinct sinks -- I suspect that might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to isolate slots and force the YARN to provide additional task managers and slots will be to use [Slot Sharing Groups](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups) for operations you want to isolate. By default all operations are put into the `default` slot sharing group and therefore all your tasks share the same slot.

To do it, just specify a different slot sharing group for different jobs after operators you want to isolate:

```scala
strean
   .op(...)
   .slotSharingGroup("job-N")
```

Comment: Thanks. I also thought of same approach. If there is no other option explicitly given by flink to increase taskmanagers, i will try this one.

Comment: The root issue here is not the Task Managers count, but the way the operators got assigned to slots. Until they share the slot, no new slots will be allocated until the parallelism meets. You can artifitially increase the task managers count by setting `-s 1`               - Number of slots per TaskManager - but this will only increase the task managers count to 20 in your case.

Comment: Thanks. As of now job is working fine. I am giving every 20 sink task a fixed slot group. Just wanted to know how we can distribute source sub-task to different taskmanagers. I want to maximize co-location of source sub-task with sink tasks.

Comment: Here is a kind of similar question  I asked some time ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607665/apache-flink-is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-slot-sharing-groups. I've provided a workaround but not sure whether it will help in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this.